IJCAD Electrical　接点表の属性『SA○○XREF』 をVBAで書き換えたい
現状、接点表のリファレンス表現は例えば『1-A-9（図面番号＋列番号＋行番号）』となっております。
しかしながら弊社の表現は、『Z1A（図面に付加した２桁の記号＋列番号）』となっております。
そこで、VBAのマクロを使って、接点表の SA○○XREFの値を書き替えたいと思います。
しかしながら、SA○○XREF にアクセスするための記述が分かりません。
（まだVBAを使い始めたばかりなので、『ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.』で、図面全体のオブジェクトを検索対象とし、『AcDbBlockReference』という名のブロック内（接点表）のどこかに SA○○XREF があると思うのですが、見つかりません）
お手数ですが、SA○○XREF にアクセスするための記述をご教示ください。
